# PHP error verifying login using a post request

Tags: php, validation, authentication

I tried a simple code for making a login. It works perfectly fine when I submit details and give a correct response on the screen but when I load it for first time on browser it displays an error message saying:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\wamp\www\test\first.php on line 14
and
Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\wamp\www\test\first.php on line 15
```

Can't identify the problem it has.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My First PHP Program!</title>
         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
          <p>username <input type="text" name="usser"/></p>
          <p>password <input type="password" name="pass" /></p>
          <p>   <input type="submit" name="submit"  /></p>
        </form>
        <?php 
            $name = $_REQUEST['usser']; 
            $pas=$_REQUEST['pass'];
            if($name=="mandeep"&&$pas=="mani"){
                echo "successful";
            }
            else{
                echo "Login Failed";
            }
       ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for new post for form

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $name = $_REQUEST['usser']; 
    $pas=$_REQUEST['pass'];
   if($name=="mandeep"&&$pas=="mani"){
  echo "successful";
   }
   else{
   echo "Login Failed";
   } }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify if that variable is setted first. And I recommend you to use `$_POST` variables if you are using post action. And use `===` for identical comparisons.

```
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['usser']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
            $name = $_POST['usser']; 
            $pas= $_POST['pass'];
            if($name === "mandeep" && $pas === "mani"){
                echo "successful";
            }
            else{
                echo "Login Failed";
            }
        }
   ?>
```

[POST php reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)
[PHP comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Probably because you're dumping code without explaining what you've changed (before edit), answering a question that has been answered many times before and not explaining what else is wrong with this code.

Comment: cool..this helped..bt can u tell me d diff between using $_POST and $_REQUEST?

Comment: @user3185620 Requests gets the value of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` variables

Answer (score 0):

As the page loads you still run the code in the php block after the form.

You could use isset to validate that it's been set.